# Working with jBoss and .war

Tags: jboss, war

I was hoping to get some advice on what to do. I have a .war file containing RESTful calls that I got to work by deploying them using jBoss 5. I want to host a simple html file in the same local domain (localhost:8080) to make a sample rest call using jQuery.ajax(). Should I download Apache to host these files in localhost:8080? Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Apache I am assuming you mean Apache Web Server or Apache Httpd. In that case, no you do not need apache for hosting an HTML file. You can package the html files along with the javascript and images files in your war.

Here is a sample of how your war can be packaged.

```
webapp.war
 |
 |---> WEB-INF
 |      |----> web.xml
 |      |----> classes
 |              |----> MyResource.properties
 |              |----> RestfulService.class
 |---> index.html
 |---> javascript
 |       |---> jQuery.js
 |---> images
 |       |---> logo.gif
```

Hope this helps.

Good luck!